# Cannot delete a row because of foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. `user` and `comment`. I wanted the users to be able to vote up comments so I made another table called `user_vote_comment`. I let the `id` column on the `user` table and the `id` column on the `comment` table be a composite primary key on the `user_vote_comment` table.

[image]

This is the structure of the `user_vote_comment` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_vote_comment` (
  `user_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `comment_id`),
  INDEX `fk_user_vote_comment_comment1_idx` (`comment_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_vote_comment_user1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_vote_comment_comment1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`comment_id`)
    REFERENCES `comment` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

Now I added some rows to the `user_vote_comment` but then I wanted to delete some votes because I wanted the users to have that option, to unvote. But then I get this error message:

```
Error 1451: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`user_vote_comment`, CONSTRAINT `fk_user_vote_comment_comment1` FOREIGN KEY (`comment_id`) REFERENCES `comment` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I thought the user and comment table were the parent tables here? Since it makes sense that it is a constraint if I was to delete a user or a comment then I should get an error because some rows in the `user_vote_comment` are dependent on that info, but not the other way around?

I don't understand why I can't delete the rows in the `user_vote_comment`, I feel that I am too much restricted if I can't even remove rows from it.

What should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure why you get a foreign key constraint fails when trying to delete a row from `user_vote_comment`  but, `ON DELETE NO ACTION`  will prevent deletion of a row in `comment` or `user` table which is referenced by a row in `user_vote_comment` table to avoid orphan entries

Same thing goes for `ON UPDATE NO ACTION`, which will prevent updating the primary key of rows in `comment` or `user` which is referenced by `user_vote_comment` table. 

As for the consistency of data, I think you should specify `ON DELETE CASCADE` if you allow the deletion of users and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anything is wrong with your SQL. May be you've missed mentioning something else in the above problem which is causing the issue?

I did a quick test with SQLFiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c726aa/1/0) and I'm able to delete from USER_VOTE_COMMENT table just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can set `ON DELETE CASCADE` instead of `ON DELETE NO ACTION`

Comment: Won't that try to delete all the users and comments? Since it thinks they are children tables, when it should be opposite.